How to remove the #iss from my application url when using Keycloak?
I am using the Keycloak for my application, when I get redirected back or refresh my application I can see this URL I in my browser, how can I remove the #iss from it?
https://my-app.com/items#iss=https://my-app.com:8443/realms/rm&iss=https://my-app.com:8443/realms/rm

and it is appending it on every refresh.

This was added in keycloak 23, read more about it here https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/upgrading/index.html#migrating-to-23-0-0. You can disable this in config.

@ch4mp if I knew what configuration I needed to add to the question I would have added them, if you need more information you can simply ask. Relating my reputation to the lack of some configurations which is clearly what I am asking about is quite useless.


Posting what @lukap123456 shared in the comment.
